# Craft 3 composer installation

Tags: database, craft3, composer

I have installed Craft with Composer and have run the set up command.

When I type in my database name I always get the error:

`Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have tried with a Mamp Pro server set up (restarted as per another post) and with a different username (I can't seem to set a password in terminal during the setup?).  Any ideas how I can get past this final hurdle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to enter the database information in your `.env` file?

Your password is usually `"root"` in a MAMP environment.